# Is it possible to start a call in Google Hangout using code?

Tags: android, android-intent, voip, skype, google-hangouts

Is it possible to call hangout user from android programatically as what we do in Skype `(Skype:username?call&video=true)` ? I tried for Skype and it's working fine. But I didn't get a proper solution for Hangouts. I saw code units in android to call Hangouts through link, but I didn't get a proper solution to call a hangout user from Hangouts installed on the android device.

For Skype I have this:

```
 Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 String contactUserName="helpdesk";

 skypeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + contactUserName + "?call&video=true"));
```

The above code calls the corresponding Skype user by accessing the installed Skype Application on the android device.

Similarly I would like to do the same for Hangouts. i.e. to make a call from android phone programatically from hangouts to hangouts.

It will be help full if i get a Solution for ooVoo too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Plus Platform issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=385), it is not possible to do such thing yet.

Perhaps you may want to join the people asking for that feature in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw code units in android to call Hangouts through link, but I
>   didn't get a proper solution to call a hangout user from Hangouts
>   installed on the android device.

You could use the link, there is probably a broadcast receiver on android that will launch the Android app if it detects that link.

And I saw the other answer, but if you're willing to go the undocumented route (which is not usually recommended and which you use at your own risk). You should check the Google Hangout apk for an undocumented open intent. If it has an open intent, it should appear as ascii text in the middle of the manifest file, after you renamed its apk extension to zip, and unzipped it to find the compiled manifest file inside.